# Waiting subscribe inside a foreach to end

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

So im new in terms of rxjs and i know that probably the answer to my question envolves do pipes. however, i already did that and never works. The method i have is a method that draw paths in a map  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4OvI.jpg)

To do so, i need to getAllLines from my db and get an array of [linePaths like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0NKE.png)..After that i get the pathKey inside of that array and i findByKey the path and get a list of pathObjects. each pathObject contains an array of [pathNodes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9VRT.png).. so what i have to do is go inside each pathNode and get the NodeObject by the key that pathNode Contains. i do this because each node contains latitude and longitude to mark on the map. for example, in the last image i send Node1 connects to Node:15 which connects to Node:13 and so on. the problem is that im trying to do a subscribe inside a forEach and for that reason my program kinda explodes. many solutions are shown when i F5 and when i try to end a path by the final node in pathNodes it keeps me connecting the lastNode of that list to the begin node of another PathNodeArray.

Im gonna show my code sample

```js
this.lineService.getAll()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.lines = data;
      //console.log(this.lines);
      this.lines.forEach((element: any) => element.linePaths[0].linePath.forEach((element: any) => {
        //console.log(element);
        this.pathService.findByKey(element.path)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.paths = data;
              //console.log(this.paths);
              let observables: Observable < any > [] = [];
              this.paths.pathNodes[0].pathNode.forEach((element: any) => {
                //console.log(element);
                observables.push(element.node);
              })
              const arrayToStore: any = [];
              observables.forEach((element: any) => {
                this.nodeService.findByKey(element)
                  .subscribe(
                    (data: any) => {
                      this.nodeToSearch = data;
                      arrayToStore.push(data);
                      for (let i = 0; i < arrayToStore.length - 1; i++) {
                        L.polyline([
                          [arrayToStore[i].latitude, arrayToStore[i].longitude],
                          [arrayToStore[i + 1].latitude, arrayToStore[i + 1].longitude]
                        ]).addTo(this.map);
                      }
                    });
              })
            }
          )
      }));
    });
```

The sample my problem shows up is this one:

```js
observables.forEach((element: any) => {
  this.nodeService.findByKey(element)
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.nodeToSearch = data;
        arrayToStore.push(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayToStore.length - 1; i++) {

          L.polyline([
            [arrayToStore[i].latitude, arrayToStore[i].longitude],
            [arrayToStore[i + 1].latitude, arrayToStore[i + 1].longitude]
          ]).addTo(this.map);
        }
      }
    );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You has a complex object so I don't know if the code can help you. It's important undersand the "thecnica" because a change in the database makes the code don't work.

To simplify you can declare three observables based in you dbs

```
const getAll=()=>this.lineService.getAll().pipe(map(x=>(
{
  name:x.name
  linePath:x.linePaths[0].linePath
})))
const getPath=(key)=>this.pathService.findByKey(key).pipe(map(x=>(
{
  key:x.key
  nodes:x.pathNodes[0].pathNode
})))
const getNode=(key)=>this.nodeService.findByKey(key).pipe(map(x=>(
{
  key:x.key
  lat:....  //I dont know how is the data from nodeService
  long:...
})))
```

So this functions return more simple objects

```
getAll() give object like
   [{name: "lordedo",linePath: [{ key: "path1" }, { key: "path2" }, { key: "path3" }]}..]
getPath(key) give object like
   {key:"path1",nodes:[{key:"node1"},{key:"node2",duration:10},{key:"node3",duration:20}]
and getNode(key) give object like
   {key:"node1",lat:10,long:20}
```

I'll try to put comments to the code to help understand, but the idea is: when we get the obs,

1. use switchMap
2. create an array of "keys"
3. create a forkJon of the array
4. transform the array of keys with the data received from the forkJoin
5. return the array

The code is

```
this.paths=getAll().pipe(switchMap(lines=>{
  const pathsKeys=lines.map(x=>x.linePath.map(x=>x.key))
    .reduce((a,b)=>[...a,...b])
    //in pathsKeys we has ["path1","path2","path3"...]
    return forkJoin(pathsKeys.map(path=>getPath(path))).pipe(
      switchMap(pathsData=>{
        //pathsData is an array [{key:..,nodes:{key:..},{key:..,nodes:{key:..}...]
        const nodesKeys=pathsData.map(x=>x.nodes).reduce((a,b)=>[...a,...b])
           .map(x=>x.key)
        //nodesKey is an array with values repeats ["node1","node2","node1","node3"..]
        const nodesUniq=nodesKeys
           .filter((n,index)=>nodesKeys.indexOf(n)==index)
        //nodes uniq are an array with uniq values ["node1","node2",...]
        return forkJoin(nodesUniq.map(x=>getNode(x))).pipe(map((nodesData:any)=>{
          //nodesData is an array with the data of the nodes
          //[{key:..,lat:..,long:..},{key:..,lat:..,long:..}...]

          //we are going to transform "lines"
          //remember: in pathsData we have an array with the data of the paths
          //          in nodesData we has an array with the data of the nodes
          lines.forEach(line=>{
            line.linePath.forEach(p=>{
              //for each line we add the property "nodes" and "duration"
              const path=pathsData.find(x=>x.key==p.key)
              p["nodes"]=[...path.nodes]
              p["duration"]=0
              p["nodes"].forEach(n=>{
                p["duration"]=p["duration"]+(n.duration?n.duration:0)
                delete n.duration
                const node=nodesData.find(y=>y.key==n.key)
                //for each node we add the properties "lat" and "long"
                n["lat"]=node["lat"]
                n["long"]=node["long"]
              })
            })
          })
          return lines
        }))
      })
    )
}))
```

If we subscribe to this.paths we get the data we need

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vupnxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)